# How to update Recyclerview image at position after downloading the image from internet?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my recyclerview after the download of the image is complete `onSuccess` method, however calling `notifyItemChanged(position);` doesn't work, I want to update the recyclerview at position once the `onSuccess` is called. The temporary solution is to call each time `notifyDataSetChanged();` but it messes with the images and their scale. Can I update the recyclerview when an image is successfully downloaded? How can I solve this? I could update everything when everything is downloaded but android studio suggests to not use notifyDataSetChanged.
I know the `ImageLoader` class might (and probably is) inefficient or not greatly coded so please if you want suggest me changes that helps me improve it, I don't need to know how bad it is, I know

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
 
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
 
import java.util.List;
 
public class ComicViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComicViewAdapter.ComicViewHolder> {
 
    Context context;
    List<String> linksList;
 
    public ComicViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> linksList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.linksList = linksList;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PrefUtils.PREF))
            PrefUtils.with(context).setSharedPref(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    }
 
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ComicViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comic_view_pager, parent, false);
        return new ComicViewHolder(view);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ComicViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Manga.imageLoader.with(context, context.getCacheDir() + "/cache").load(Manga.resolveURL(linksList.get(position), context),
                holder.comic_page, new LoadImage() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        holder.comic_page.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                    }
 
                    @Override
                    public void onFail() {
 
                    }
                }, null);
    }
 
 
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return linksList.size();
    }
 
    static class ComicViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 
        private final ImageView comic_page;
 
        public ComicViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            comic_page = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comic_page);
        }
    }
}
```

The class used "ImageLoader" and it's classes can be found ImageLoader: https://pastebin.com/mi3txZ7d MemoryCache: https://pastebin.com/PcikSwfX FileCache: https://pastebin.com/wKv2Du2g

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RawRes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ImageLoader {

    private final Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<>());
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private FileUtils fileUtils;
    private Context context;
    private boolean asBitmap = false;

   /* public static ImageLoader with(Context _context, String path) {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
        imageLoader.fileCache = new FileCache(path);
        imageLoader.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        imageLoader.fileUtils = new FileUtils();
        imageLoader.context = _context;
        imageLoader.init();
        return imageLoader;
    }
    public static ImageLoader with(Context _context) {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
        imageLoader.fileCache = new FileCache(_context);
        imageLoader.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        imageLoader.fileUtils = new FileUtils();
        imageLoader.context = _context;
        return imageLoader;
    }*/

    public static ImageLoader get() {
        return new ImageLoader();
    }

    public ImageLoader with(Context _context, String path) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(path);
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        fileUtils = new FileUtils();
        context = _context;
        /*init();*/
        return this;
    }

    public void fileCache(Context _context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(_context);
    }

    public void fileCache(String path) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(path);
    }

    public ImageLoader with(Context _context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(_context);
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        fileUtils = new FileUtils();
        context = _context;
        /*init();*/
        return this;
    }

    public void init() {
        memoryCache.loadCache(fileCache.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public ImageLoader asBitmap() {
        asBitmap = true;
        return this;
    }

    public void load(String url, ImageView imageView, LoadImage loadImage, ConnectionErrors connectionErrors) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();
        } else {
            imageViews.put(imageView, url);
            queuePhoto(url, imageView, loadImage, connectionErrors);
        }
    }

    public void load(byte[] bytes, ImageView imageView, LoadImage loadImage, ConnectionErrors connectionErrors) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        Base64Utils.Base64Encoder encoder = new Base64Utils.Base64Encoder();
        String url = encoder.encrypt(Arrays.toString(bytes), Base64.NO_WRAP, null);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();
        } else {
            imageViews.put(imageView, url);
            queuePhoto(bytes, imageView, loadImage, connectionErrors);
        }
    }


    public void load(Bitmap bitmap, ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void load(@RawRes @DrawableRes @NonNull Integer resourceId, ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView, LoadImage loadImage, ConnectionErrors connectionErrors) {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executor.submit(new PhotoLoader(photoToLoad, loadImage, connectionErrors));
    }

    public void queuePhoto(byte[] bytes, ImageView imageView, LoadImage loadImage, ConnectionErrors connectionErrors) {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad = new PhotoToLoad(bytes, imageView);
        executor.submit(new PhotoLoader(photoToLoad, loadImage, connectionErrors));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url, ConnectionErrors connectionErrors) {
        File file = fileCache.getFile(url);
        Bitmap _image = fileUtils.decodeFile(file);
        if (_image != null)
            return _image;
        try {
            Bitmap _webImage;
            URL imageURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
            connection.setReadTimeout(0);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileUtils.copyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            is.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            _webImage = fileUtils.decodeFile(file);
            return _webImage;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {
            if (connectionErrors != null)
                connectionErrors.OutOfMemory(memoryCache);
            else
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            if (connectionErrors != null)
                connectionErrors.FileNotFound(url);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            if (connectionErrors != null)
                connectionErrors.NormalError();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] bytes) {
        Base64Utils.Base64Encoder encoder = new Base64Utils.Base64Encoder();
        File file = fileCache.getFile(encoder.encrypt(Arrays.toString(bytes), Base64.NO_WRAP, null));
        Bitmap _image = fileUtils.decodeFile(file);
        if (_image != null)
            return _image;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad _photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(_photoToLoad.imageView);
        return tag == null || !tag.equals(_photoToLoad.url);
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

    static class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public byte[] bytes;

        public PhotoToLoad(String _url, ImageView _imageView) {
            url = _url;
            imageView = _imageView;
        }

        public PhotoToLoad(byte[] _bytes, ImageView _imageView) {
            bytes = _bytes;
            imageView = _imageView;
        }
    }

    class PhotoLoader implements Runnable {

        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        LoadImage loadImage;
        ConnectionErrors connectionErrors;

        PhotoLoader(PhotoToLoad _photoToLoad, LoadImage _loadImage, ConnectionErrors _connectionErrors) {
            photoToLoad = _photoToLoad;
            loadImage = _loadImage;
            connectionErrors = _connectionErrors;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bitmap;
            if (asBitmap) {
                bitmap = getBitmap(photoToLoad.bytes);
                Base64Utils.Base64Encoder encoder = new Base64Utils.Base64Encoder();
                String bytes = encoder.encrypt(Arrays.toString(photoToLoad.bytes), Base64.NO_WRAP, null);
                memoryCache.put(bytes, bitmap);
            } else {
                bitmap = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url, connectionErrors);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bitmap);
            }
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Displacer displacer = new Displacer(bitmap, photoToLoad, loadImage);
            executor.execute(displacer);
            photoToLoad.imageView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    public class Displacer implements Runnable {

        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        LoadImage loadImage;

        public Displacer(Bitmap bitmap, PhotoToLoad photoToLoad, LoadImage _loadImage) {
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
            this.loadImage = _loadImage;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(() -> {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    if (loadImage != null)
                        loadImage.onSuccess(bitmap);
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    photoToLoad.imageView.invalidate();
                } else {
                    if (loadImage != null)
                        loadImage.onFail();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MemoryCache {

    private final Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<>(10, 1.5f, true));
    private long size = 0;
    private long imageSize;
    private long limit = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    public MemoryCache() {
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
    }

    public void loadCache(String path) {
        File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
            for (File file : files) {

                if (!cache.containsKey(file.getAbsolutePath()))
                    try {
                        cache.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), getBitmap(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())));
                        System.out.println("cache doesn't contain " + file.getPath() + " adding it");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(byte[] bytes) {
        Base64Utils.Base64Encoder encoder = new Base64Utils.Base64Encoder();
        FileUtils fileUtils = new FileUtils();
        File file = new File(encoder.encrypt(Arrays.toString(bytes), Base64.NO_WRAP, null));
        Bitmap _image = fileUtils.decodeFile(file);
        if (_image != null)
            return _image;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    public void setLimit(long _limit) {
        limit = _limit;
    }


    public Bitmap get(String id) {
        try {
            if (!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            return cache.get(id);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void remove(String id) {
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(id)) {
                size -= sizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
                cache.remove(id);
                checkSize();
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCacheValid(String id, int size) {
        System.out.println(sizeInBytes(cache.get(id)) + " / " + size);
        return sizeInBytes(cache.get(id)) == size;
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(id))
                size -= sizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size += sizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        if (size > limit) {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Bitmap>> iterator = cache.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> entry = iterator.next();
                size -= sizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iterator.remove();
                if (size <= limit)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try {
            cache.clear();
            size = 0;
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long sizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap == null)
            return 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
        return imageInByte.length;
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class FileCache {

    private final File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context) {
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public FileCache(String path) {
        cacheDir = new File(path);
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url) {
        String file_name = null;
        try {
            file_name = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (file_name != null) {
            return new File(cacheDir, file_name);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public File getCacheDir() {
        return cacheDir;
    }

    public long lenght() {
        long size = 0;
        size += cacheDir.length();
        for (File file : cacheDir.listFiles()) {
            if (file != null && file.isFile())
                size += file.length();
        }
        return size;
    }

    public int size() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files != null)
            return files.length;
        return 0;
    }

    public void clear() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null)
            return;
        for (File file : files)
            file.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it on the UI thread?

```
runOnUiThread(() -> notifyItemChanged(position));
```

Comment: Using specifically this method no but I did use https://pastebin.com/haELAEDY which does everything asynchronously and didn't do anything

Comment: UI needs to be updated on the UI thread, not asynchronously. So try this.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work, I tried to run on UI thread the adapter#notifyItemChanged

Comment: If I change the imageView base height from wrap_content to a fixed height it works even without calling notifyItemChanged